# Securing Azure App Service API calls without passing user credentials

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin, azure-app-service-plans

I have a Xamarin forms mobile application that is accessing my app service up in azure.  I want to secure the APIs so that only my client application can access them.  The mobile app does it's own user/password authentication/authorization, so I don't need AD or a 3rd party for that.  I just want to secure my APIs.  All examples I can find seems to assume there is an AD user authenticated and I can pass a token from that.  Is there a simple way to use the Azure "expose api" functionality without using an AD user?  The mobile app is using REST api calls, so I'm also struggling with how to even pass in a proper authentication token if I can put one together.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to secure is adding an API Management in front of your API's and require subscription, then only calls with a specific `ocp-apim-subscription-key` will be accepted. I don't recomment storing the ocp-apim-subscription-key value in your app as anytime you need to change it, a new version of the app will be required. I recommend returning it after a succesful login by your users, this way, you're free to rotate the ocp-apim-subscription-key key when needed.

Comment: Thanks - it does look like a good option, but I'd prefer to not incur the additional cost.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to validate the client application only and not the end user, you should either look into OAuth 2.0 - which has a more complex implementation since it encompasses both application and end user authentications - or you could set up JWT authentication which is simpler and which purpose is to authenticate either client applications or end users, not both at the same time like OAuth.

After your implement the authentication on your API(s), you send over the generated token(s) over a Authentication header on your Requests.

Comment: thanks, this is more what I'm looking for.  can you point me to any references on how to implement JWT in this type of scenario?

Comment: I believe it will change greatly based on the language/framework you are currently using for your API(s). Some may be simpler than others.

Comment: It’s a c#, Xamarin mobile app.

Comment: I understand. Your Xamarin mobile app is the client application, while you have one or more APIs as an Azure Service App. After implementing JWT in this Azure Service App, which changes according to the language(s)/framework(s) used in it, like a .Net Core API, or an Express.js API, you implement the Authentication header on the requests sent by the client app to these APIs.